# What is the standard notation for $\arcsin$

Tags: trigonometry, notation

I found a lecture notes that claims the following. Is this standard?

The notation $\overline{\text{arc}}\text{ sin }x$ is the inverse function of $\sin x$ restricted to $\left [ -\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right ]$ and $\text{arc sin }x $ mean all those $y$ satisfying $\sin x=y.$

Comment: $\arctan$, $\tan^{-1}$ are usually used.

Comment: Why are you using `\text{arc sin}` rather than `\arcsin`? ($\arcsin$)?

Comment: If I saw correctly, the notes has a space between the letters c and s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common notation used is either $\,\arcsin x\,$ or $\,\sin^{-1}x$.

When the desired value of $\,f(x) = \arcsin x\,$ is restricted to those values lying in $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$, this is usually stated explicitly. I presume the lecturer introduced $\overline{\text{arc}}\sin x$ to spare the need from restricting the range of solutions repeatedly.

Comment: So is $\arcsin x$ the set of all solutions to $\sin y=x$ or is it just some real number satisfying the equation?

Comment: @amWhy I disagree. $\arcsin x$ is a function in its own right, defined over $[-1,1]$ and taking values on $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.

Comment: I don't think I've said anything to contradict that, @Pedro.

Comment: Your last comment.

Comment: forumreader: Yes, $y= \arcsin x$ is the set of solutions to $\sin y = x$, where $y \in [-\pi/2, \pi/2]$

Comment: There is only one solution!

Comment: Yes, Pedro, you're right, that goes without saying. (Egad, now it's me with the grammatical oversight!) ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: Needs a TU -> +1